# Why no memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free, malloc

The following is designed to take a variable length constant char and print it out in a nice format for logging.  I am certain readers will have suggestions on how this can be improved, and I'd welcome it.

What puzzles me is that I expected it would be necessary to free() the returned static char each time ToHexString() is called.  Instead, I see no memory leak whatsoever.  Even tho I use the function inline and therefore do not assign its return value to a variable.

I created a simple test that calls this function in a loop, each time with a different length cString and nMaxChars parameter.  Then I watched VM status.  The memory allocation for my test program, and free memory, never changed.

It seems to me it should have increased each time a malloc is called and no free.

```
static char *ToHexString(const char *cString,int nMaxChars)
{
    static char *cStr;



    /*if (80>strlen(cString))
        nRawChars=strlen(cString);
    if (nMaxChars>nRawChars)
        nRawChars=nMaxChars;
    */
    if (nMaxChars==0)
        nMaxChars=80;

    printf("There are %i chars\n",nMaxChars);

    char *cStr1;
    char *cStr2;
    char *cStr3;
    int nLen=nMaxChars*6;
    cStr=calloc(nLen,sizeof(char));

    cStr1=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    cStr2=calloc(nLen,sizeof(char));
    cStr3=calloc(nLen,sizeof(char));
    cStr1[0]='\0';
    cStr2[0]='\0';
    cStr3[0]='\0';
    int nC1=0;
    int nRowCnt=0;

    for (nC1=0;nC1<nMaxChars;nC1++)
    {
        ++nRowCnt;
        if (cString[nC1]==0x00)
            snprintf(cStr1,8,"[00] ");
        else
            snprintf(cStr1,8,"[%02x] ",(unsigned char)cString[nC1]);

        if ( (nRowCnt%8==0) )
        {
            snprintf(cStr3,nLen,"%s%s\n",cStr2,cStr1);
        }
        else
            snprintf(cStr3,nLen,"%s%s",cStr2,cStr1);

        snprintf(cStr2,nLen,"%s",cStr3);
    }
    snprintf(cStr,nLen,"%s",cStr3);
    free(cStr1);
    free(cStr2);
    free(cStr3);
    return(cStr);
}
```

Here is the calling routine:

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    memset(&cBuff, 0,255);
    printf("Reading %s now..\n",cPort);
    while (sleep(1)==-1);
    nChars=read(nPort, cBuff, 255);
    //printf("Read %i chars from %s\n",nChars,cPort);
    if (nChars<=0)
        printf("Read 0 chars from %s\n",cPort);
    else
        printf("Read %i chars from %s\n%s\n",nChars,cPort,ToHexString(cBuff,nChars));
}
```

Comment: Your resolution is probably too small. Your OS probably allocates 4-8k pages. Unless you free that, you do have a leak, you probably just can't see it because these allocations are tiny.

Comment: @Jason - you are probably right. I thought that a static pointer would retain the same address (it would, if he only called calloc once and then realloc subsequently).

Comment: Run that code through valgrind, you'll see the leak.

Comment: Run it for 100,000 or even 1,000,000 times with large strings

Comment: @Tim Post: The address of the pointer itself is maintained because of the static scope, but the address of the allocated block to which it points changes with each invocation of the function and is then discarded with the next invocation upon reassignment. He /should/ just be allocating a single block the first time through and then realloc if the max length changes, but he's not :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is a leak:

```
static void memeat(void)
{
        static char *foo = NULL;

        foo = malloc(1024);

        return;

}
```

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) output:

```
==16167== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16167==    definitely lost: 4,096 bytes in 4 blocks
==16167==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16167==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16167==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==16167==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16167== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Note, `still reachable` (1024 bytes) is the result of the last time `memeat()` was entered. The static pointer still held a valid reference to the last block `memeat()` allocated when the program exited. Just not the previous blocks.

The following is *NOT* a leak:

```
static void memeat(void)
{
        static char *foo = NULL;

        foo = realloc(foo, 1024);

        return;

}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==16244== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16244==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16244==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16244==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16244==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==16244==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16244== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Here, the address `foo` pointed to has been freed, and `foo` now points to the newly allocated address, and will continue to do so the next time `memeat()` is entered.

**Explanation:**

The `static` storage type says that the pointer `foo` will point to the same address as initialized each time the function is entered. However, if you *change* that address each time the function is entered via `malloc()` or `calloc()`, you've lost the reference to the blocks from the previous allocation. Hence, a leak, since either is going to return a new address.

'Still Reachable' in valgrind means that that all allocated heap blocks still have a valid pointer to access / manipulate / free them upon exit. This is similar to allocating memory in `main()` and not freeing it, just relying on the OS to reclaim memory.

In short, yes - you have a leak. However, you can fix it rather easily. Just note that you are indeed relying on your OS to reclaim the memory unless you add another argument to your function that just tells `ToHexString` to call free on the static pointer, which you could use when exiting.

Similar to this: (full test program)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static void memeat(unsigned int dofree)
{
        static char *foo = NULL;

        if (dofree == 1 && foo != NULL) {
                free(foo);
                return;
        }

        foo = realloc(foo, 1024);

        return;

}


int main(void)
{
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
                memeat(0);

        memeat(1);
        return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==16285== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16285==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16285==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 6,144 bytes allocated
==16285==
==16285== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

**Note on the final output**:

Yes, 6144 bytes were actually allocated according to what `malloc()` returned while the program ran, but that just means the static pointer was freed, then reallocated according to the number of times `memeat()` was entered. The actual heap use of the program at any given time was actually just 2*1024, 1k to allocate the new pointer while the old one still existed waiting to be copied to the new one.

Again, it should not be too hard to adjust your code, but it isn't clear to me why you are using static storage to begin with.

Comment: Tim,

Is realloc() necessary then if I do the free technique you suggest (memeat(1))?

I use static as I've had experiences where ordinary char *var get clobbered.

Comment: @k1mgy - yes, or you need to free then calloc() the static pointer if its not null. Otherwise, you lose the reference to what was allocated the last time the function was entered. While you don't need to explicitly free blocks that can still be reached at exit, its still good practice to do so, which means some means of freeing the static pointer prior to exiting would be ideal.

Comment: @k1mgy - Also, if you go the "free if not null" route when the function is entered, be sure to initialize the static pointer once freeing it each time, else you'll likely still end up leaking due to a wild pointer.

Comment: @k1mgy - And I still don't see why you are using static storage. If you are going to re-factor, perhaps just make it return a pointer to an allocated block that the caller can free, as tommieb75 suggests? I answered the particulars of your question, concerning the leak .. but the implementation still seems questionable. Or, if you know the strings will always be that small .. something like `static char retstring[1024]` ?

Comment: @Tim If I use non-static storage in the function (the variable I return must be static if the function is declared static, correct or wrong?) then I have found my return result can become corrupted.

Based on you suggestions I call ToHexString(NULL, -1).  The second parameter is interpreted as a request to free:

  static char *cStr;

  if (nMaxChars==-1)
    {
        if (cStr!=NULL)
            free(cStr);
        return("");
    }
...
    cStr=realloc(cStr,nLen);

This seems to work just fine (I am checking for NULL later).

Comment: @Tim:

Although tommieb75's idea would work nicely, it requires (a) defining a pointer, (b) calling the function, (c) formatting the returned string into another string for use and (d) freeing the pointer.

Using ToHexString(NULL,-1) allows 2 steps instead of four.

As I don't know how large the return string can get, I can't reserve memory for this purpose, as in static char retstring[1024];

Comment: @k1mgy: In response to your comment to Tim there, a programmer will be thanking you for not having to refactor/chase down an 'anomaly' with leaks... he/she will be worshipping the ground you walked on if your went 4 steps instead of 2! :)

Comment: @k1mgy, I really think you are falling victim to micro optimization here. Sure you can add another level of indirection to avoid free()'s in a loop by the caller and just operate on the given pointer, but would it really help? The fact remains, you are dealing with a few bytes, as evidenced by the fact that you did not see the leak in the first place :) I'd just plug the tiny hole in the dam and move on to more important things. Optimize later.

Comment: @k1mgy: I have to agree with Tim on this, falling for these micro-optimization 'tricks' can be counter-productive... get it working first, then leave the optimization (if any) later on, because with optimizations, the code may/can break...always have valgrind and splint in your toolchest when dealing with this kind of thing and to be a happier programmer armed with those tools that you can zap away this kind of subtleties in code like that... :D

Comment: @k1mgy: See the last part of my answer, I just updated it. The test program (at any given time) only has 2k allocated, 1k after realloc() returns. I hope I did not frighten you into micro optimization by posting the final Valgrind output without explanation :)

Comment: @all: although I appreciate the suggestion of Tim and others regarding the avoidance of "micro-optimization", I decided to go with the suggestion of re-entering the function with a parameter which then calls a free() and returns.  This is the 2 versus 4 step solution.  The reason I did this are that it works and that as ToHexString() is called in a number of places, setup of the result of ToHexString would require creation of yet another char * that would have to be calloc'd, then snprintf'd, used, and then freed.  I've reduced complexity and chance of error (I think) with doing the 2-step.

Answer (score 1):

It is a memory leak. If you persistently call the function the memory used by the program increases. For example:

```
int main() {
   while (1) {
      ToHexString("testing the function", 20);
   }
}
```

If you run this and watch the process with a system monitoring tool you will see that the used memory is constantly increasing.

The leak is probably not obvious in your program because the function only leaks a few bytes each call and is not called very often. So the increase in memory usage is not very noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out two things that crosses my mind when inspecting the code:

```
cStr=calloc(nLen,sizeof(char));
```

Why did you not do error checking on this.... as I can see from the code, there is zero checking on the assumption memory WILL always be available....dangerous.... **ALWAYS** check for ***NULL*** pointer on return from a memory allocation function call such as `calloc`, `malloc` and `realloc`...it will **ALWAYS** be the onus on the programmer to manage the `free`'ing up of pointers to return them back to the heap.

Also, because you have `cStr` declared as a static pointer to `char *`, you are not freeing it up at all in fact this line proves it:

```
printf("Read %i chars from %s\n%s\n",nChars,cPort,ToHexString(cBuff,nChars));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You would be better off to do it this way:

```
char *hexedString;
hexedString = ToHexString(cBuff, nChars);
....
printf("Read %i chars from %s\n%s\n",nChars,cPort,hexedString);
....
free(hexedString);
```

Comment: Thanks tommieb75.  I've been rather cavalier with malloc and calloc.  No more :)

Answer (score 0):

You return the result of your routine in a fresh array. With your model, the responsibility to free this array with the result is in the caller. So there, in the caller, you should store the result of your routine in a temporary, do whatever you want with it, and then free() it at the end.